# Java Program to read text file

Tags: java

I have a text file like

```
vinoth   5001   chennai    programmer
ramesh   7755   madurai    tester
suresh   7452   namakal    designer
salim    4652   salem      programmer
```

I want to find with their designation but want to save their other details in an array. how can i do that? any suggestions

Comment: Please, give more information. Which of the columns is designation? Can any of the columns contain whitespaces? Is there anything other special about any of the columns(for instance is the second always 4 digits)?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `String.substring(start, end)` to get the relevant part of the line.
- Call `trim()` on it.

Comment: thanks for ur help. if u can provide me a program please provode it

Comment: @Javid Make an attempt, ask questions when you get stuck

Comment: Thanks for spelling words like 'your' correctly.  If you can provide me money, please provide it.

Comment: If you know none of the entries will contain spaces you could use `String.split(" ")`, but I prefer Andrew's approach

Comment: @Mad So do I! As soon as the data was formatted and it became obvious this was 'fixed column width', `substring()` just jumped out at me.

Answer (score 1):

- Read the file line by line
- call `String.split` to split the different informations into an array
- You can store these information in a `Map` whose key would be the username `vinoth` and values would be the array you just received from `String.split`
- Even better you store these informations in an object that represents something with the properties you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Read each line using buffered reader and then do that:

```
HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>;

// read the line here
String line = ...;
String strings[] = line.split(" ");
String designation = strings[3];
values.put(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
```